# Duplo block with facecloth or towel on

Tags: duplo

I'm currently kitting out a new bathroom for my Lego son, and I would like to modify a set of drawers, including using Duplo pieces as labels for the drawer contents.
I've found Duplo blocks for toothbrushes/toothpaste, toilet rolls, shampoo/soap etc like these ones:

[image] [image]

but I'd like one for the drawer containing flannels (washcloths for faces).

So I'm looking for a Duplo block, preferably 1x2x2, with a picture of a towel or a washcloth or similar, but can't find a suitable one. Can anyone suggest a suitable block?

(also a 1x2x2 toothbrush/toothpaste block, if one exists)

Answer (score 8):

I have gone through [32 pages](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=duplo%201x2x2#T=P) of 1x2x2 bricks, and there do not appear to be any towel bricks.  (There are, however [alternate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4066pb132&name=Duplo,%20Brick%201%20x%202%20x%202%20with%20Shampoo%20and%20Soap%20Containers%20Pattern&category=%5BDuplo,%20Brick,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=7) [soaps](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49570pb04&name=Duplo,%20Brick%204%20x%202%20x%203%20Slope%20with%20Mirror,%20Toothbrushes,%20Soap%20and%20Whale%20Pattern&category=%5BDuplo,%20Brick,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=1))

The only sets that I can find with towels all use [cloth ones](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=duplo%20towel#T=P)

Comment: Thanks, I saw the alternate soaps, there are multiple of those, but apparently no towels!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I could not find any towel blocks, and trust me, I have looked and looked just as @Chronocidal did, and the closest block I could find was this and sorry its not even Duplo: https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-brick-1-x-6-x-5-with-green-towel-sticker-hairdressing-salon-3754
But I guess you could take a white brick: https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-duplo-brick-1-x-2-x-2-with-bottom-tube-15847-76371
and custom design one of your own by designing a sticker and adding it on.

Comment: Thanks. The Lego towel may be a reasonable choice - I was only after Duplo because I knew that several of the pieces existed. And making a sticker (or directly painting/drawing a design on is my backup option.

Answer (score 2):

You might get a good result with a water-transfer decal.  However that could be quite permanent.

A satisfactory effect might be achieved by simply printing a small icon onto some paper, cut out with scissors, and then glue it to the brick.  You can also get sheets of plain white or clear sticker paper for printing onto directly, fill the page with icons to save paper.

Glues and adhesives tend to stick poorly to smooth plastic, so the sticker could be peeled off easily.  Or if you want to make it permanent, tooth up the plastic with some sandpaper before applying.

Another option might be to paint directly on the block with model paints, though this would need a steady hand and an artistic ability.